# In Perforce how do you view history of all changelists in repository?

Tags: perforce

I am not after history of a specific file but of the whole revision tree.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want just a big list of all changelists?

At the command line:

```
> p4 changelists
```

For more detailed output:

```
> p4 changelists -l
```

To see more information on a specific changelist:

```
> p4 changelist [changelistnumber]
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. However, is there a way to see the history in some existing user interface?

Comment: @Boris Lipschitz the View->Submitted Changelists menu option in P4V will show you all changelists. There's a similar option in P4Win. Alternatively you can try a tool like `p4search`: http://www.eddiescholtz.com/entry/perforce-search-released

Comment: Actually, "View -> Submitted Changelists" shows only changelists that I submitted. On the other hand, View -> History shows all changelists. I couldn't find this option in P4Win. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Huh.  In P4V, it's completely different. History shows the submissions for a particular car. Submitted Changelists has a filter that defaults to your user name, but you can change this to any user or no user to see all submissions.

Answer (score 3):

In P4V 2009.2 (at minimum) `View -> Submitted Changelists` allows you to filter the list of all changelists by folder/file, user, or workspace, as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: P4V View Submitted Changelists]

Answer (score 2):

If you use P4V

View the Submitted Tab in P4V or select the root depot and view the history tab.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to see the history log in p4v just follow the below step.
select the file to which you want to see the history log .
right click on it and select file history.
note :if you want entire history of a file starting from version1.0 to version x.0 just right click on the file and select revision graph as shown in picture.[file history in p4v](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0jZH.png)